# How can I change the URL path in asp.net 4.x on IIS 6 with Apache Load Balancer

Tags: asp.net, apache, mod-rewrite, iis, load-balancing

I need for the response path to be the original path requested by the user, for the following scenario:

I have the Apache LoadBalancer sending requests for a page to a different page when they pass a rewriterule. However, when it get to IIS I have a single file handler created to serve up the content of the request (different for each request) for both requested pages.

In other words, if the user asks for blahblahblah.txt and gets a rewriterule for yadayadayada.txt, the file handler will deal with the content for either request, but I want the user to only see that they asked for blahblahblah.txt.

My Apache rewrite rule looks similar to:

```
RewriteRule ^/blahblahblah.txt /yadayadayada.txt [R=302,NC,L]
```

My IIS web.config HttpHandler section looks similar to:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="GET" path="/blahblahblah.txt" type="CPEBiz.UI.CoreSite.CPFileHanlder"/>
  <add verb="GET" path="/yadayadayada.txt" type="CPEBiz.UI.CoreSite.CPFileHanlder"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what we were able to get to work:

> RewriteRule ^/blahblahblah.txt /yadayadayada.txt [P,NC,L]